# issue with codeIgniter fetching result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I'm trying to display zipcode which only logged in user's area.

To get user's area, `get_zipcode()` calls `get_area_name()`.

But, there is `500 error` if I get value from `get_area_name()`;

If I commented out `get_area_name()` and put harded coded value `$area ="ny"`, it works.

I think there is some issue with `get_area_name()`.

table for "`area`" is following

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wn_area` (
  `area_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `area` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`area_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=165 ;
```

Function

```
    public function get_zipcode($area_id)
    {
        $this->db->select("*");

        $this->db->from("zipcode");

        if ($area_id != "" )
        {
            $ar_area_ids = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);

            //$area = get_area_name($area_id);
            $area = "ny";

            if( in_array($area_id, $ar_area_ids) ){
                $this->db->like('sido', $area); 
            }else {
                $this->db->like('gugun', $area);
            }

        }else{  

            $this->db->like("sido", 'ny'); 
            $this->db->limit("10000");
        }


        $this->db->order_by("zipcode_id");

        $query = $this->db->get();

        return ($query->num_rows() > 0) ? $query->result() : FALSE;
    }

  public function get_area_name($area_id)
    {
        $this->db->select("*");

        $this->db->from("area");

     $this->db->where("area_id", $area_id);

        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->row()->area;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

since its class to call method from another method inside class , you need to use `$this`, like, change:

```
$area = get_area_name($area_id);
```

to

```
$area = $this->get_area_name($area_id);
```

Comment: Great. But another issue with utf-8. It returns broken characters. I checked db config and html header. They area "utf=8". Is there any way return value to set utf-8 for get_area_name